# Use NestJS framework and Neo4j

Tags: typescript, api, neo4j, nestjs

I am developing a typescript API, and i would like to use Neo4j as my database. I have tried using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nest-neo4j) package, but i get the following errors (i have followed the quick start guide):
[image]

I have also found the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9sNgCiPnhZE&list=LL), where the creator creates this package step by step, which i have not followed as of yet, because i have just installed his package.

My question is, is there a simpler way to user neo4j and nestjs or would it be a better decision to use a javascript api and neo4j (as i could just simply use the neo4j driver package in that case)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing or installed the latest `neo4j-driver`, you will need to install 4.2.3 or below to make `nest-neo4j` works.

```
npm install neo4j-driver@4.2.3
// or
yarn add neo4j-driver@4.2.3
```

For a full example, you can follow this: https://github.com/neo4j-examples/nestjs-neo4j-realworld-example

To use nestjs, you need to integrate neo4j with the framework so that it can be injected in your services. I don't think there is an easy way to use neo4j with nestjs unless you don't need the injection.

Comment: Thank you, i was using the latest version of the neo4j driver. I am now using the 4.1.1, as is used in the example you linked. By the way, do you suggest using drivine or nest-neo4j to use neo4j in nestjs?

Comment: I think you can stick with `neo4j-driver` first as there is an example for you to follow. both `drivine` and `neo4j-driver` are not quite active actually.